# Eclipse - Failed to write credentials for git repo to secure store. Error: No password provided

Tags: gitlab, eclipse-plugin

```
org.eclipse.equinox.security.storage.StorageException: No password provided.
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.security.storage.SecurePreferences.put(SecurePreferences.java:242)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.security.storage.SecurePreferencesWrapper.put(SecurePreferencesWrapper.java:128)
    at org.eclipse.egit.core.securestorage.EGitSecureStore.putCredentials(EGitSecureStore.java:66)
    at org.eclipse.egit.ui.internal.SecureStoreUtils.storeCredentials(SecureStoreUtils.java:39)
    at org.eclipse.egit.ui.internal.credentials.LoginService.login(LoginService.java:39)
    at
```

I have already tried to clear the password from keystore and windows credentials and added new password with a fresh gitlab login. Pull and Push is working properly, however password is still not saved.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am able to solve the problem by disabling the OS integration in the eclipse.
Unckeck Window -> Preferences -> General -> Security -> Secure Storage -> [OS] Integration.
Restart the eclipse and it works fine.

[image]